# Versioning concept in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, revision-history

Iam working with couchbase version 3.0.1 and use java SDK 1.4.4. Iam try for getting previous revision values for the documents. Now it can achieve by manually keeping the documents with their revision number. Is there any way to do this automatically in   SDK 1.4.4 or higher (2.0.1).

Iam useing this now for versioning.

[Versioning with Couchbase](http://blog.couchbase.com/how-implement-document-versioning-couchbase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase 3.0.1 doesn't have any changes in this regard - you'll still need to perform versioning as you would for the 2.X series.